# how to change URL parameters to stop an image reloading

Tags: jquery, url-parameters

I have an image which I only want to load one time only on the homepage, accessed via my intro page (it fades away, on load, a kind of visual echo from my intro page). I dont want the image to appear on the homepage on subsequent views, after clicking the 'home'in the nav bar .

I've been advised to either set a cookie, or use URL parameters  "to designate whether to fade the image or not"(set /index?nofade=true). I wish to try the latter, as not everyone enables cookies.

Thing is, after spending a day trawling the net, I dont know how to do either, (blushes).

Can anyone help me? I'm new to coding, so am uncertain how to write/enclose the 'no fade true' bit, I'm using jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the parameters of the url with javascript easily, then check if that particular 'nofade' param exists (or any other) and fade your image if it does

```
$(function(){
  // Grab our url parameters and split them into groups
  var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  // assign parameters to our object
  var params = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
    var hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    params[hash[0]] = hash[1];
  }
  // Now params contains your url parameters in an object
  if(typeof(params['nofade']) === 'undefined' || !params[nofade]){
    // Perform image fade here

  }
})
```

Comment: i have sorted the fading with a simple bit of jquery animation, but oh crumbs, I know this must be irritating, am struggling to understand what I have to add to your code above. So sorry.

Comment: My debugger is saying theres a syntax error on the line starting ~ if(typeof( ... but I'm not knowledgeable enough with javascript to know why and where. Can you help please? Aside from my image fade, do I have to add anything else to your script?

Comment: Whoops, sorry...was missing a ). This script tests if the nofade parameter exists in the URL, if it fails that test (nofade does NOT exist) then it will process the code in that block.

Comment: I changed the logo href in my intro page, [link](jsfiddle.net/cress/PA2gR) changed the top line ~ $(function getUrlVars(){ ~ to your script & added it myjq.js file, but no joy. I get thew feeling I'm missing something blindingly simple, that is praps taken for granted by more knowledgeable folk, but what is it? Should I be doing something to each homepage link on the other pages? When they're clicked, the animation is being triggered. Also, comparing peoples answers, 2 are slightly different. Should I add ~ var vars = [], hash; ~ as 2nd line to your code, or is it not necessary?

Comment: A complete [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qw4VV/2/) (but jsfiddle doesn't let you parse the URI)

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to sort this until late last night & all day today, about to give up then got your comment/link. Will have a look. I'm sure I'm not doing something I should be with the code.

Comment: Oh crappola, looks like I'm in for a whole load of pain, i.e apparently I have to define the params. I used your fiddle as a template, loaded the pages onto my server, but get this error reading. I've to do something, but I dont know what. I think I have to do this in Dreamweaver (using cs5.5 btw) so its yet another learning curve to deal with. Tomorrow.

Comment: debugging says theres an error with the line ~ if(typeof(params['nofade']) === 'undefined' || !params[nofade]){ . Should I be changing the'undefined' bit? But to what?

Comment: nope, that line is correct, the fiddle I posted works...I tested it and everything :)

Comment: Argh! Apologies. I must be doing something hideously wrong. Seriously about to tear my hair out. I think there must be some bunch of settings in Dreamweaver cs5.5 that I haven't set. God knows what. No jquery things seem to be working for me. Will try more tomorrow. Another example, this...[link] http://www.cressidahaughton.co.uk/Untitled-4.html ...is supposed to be a Cycle.js slide! About to give up.

Comment: Or maybe its something I have to do server side? WHY cant it be as simple as html or css?

Comment: I'd really like to get this sorted. Do I need to change some setting on my pc? (Wracking my brain).

Comment: feel free to send me an email and I'll help you figure it out - pastor_bones@yahoo.com

Comment: You sir, are a gent! :) Thankyou so much for your time, patience & effort. I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a check to see if that query string was set before your code to fade the image.

```
function getQuerystring(key, defaultVal) {
    if (defaultVal == null) {
        defaultVal = "";
    }
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)");
    var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (qs == null) {
        return defaultVal;
    }
    else {
        return qs[1];
    }
}

if(getQuerystring('nofade') == 'true'){
    //do your fading
}
```

the function uses a regular expression to parse out the query string you pass it and return its value with an optionally set default if that query string is not found

Comment: ok, so have just added your code to my jq file, put the fade bit where you have said "do your fading" but not sure what next, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you want for when someone visits  your page http://www.example.com for your logo to be there everytime they visit that page and then have to click on your logo to enter and be taken to http://www.example.com/homepage.php where your logo will fade out.

But if they subsequently reload your page you want the logo to not be there?  Is that correct.

If so, you just need to set the href on your logo to "homepage.php?fade=true".  Then you can grab that passed variable and do an if statement to see if you should just reload the page or show them the fade out.

Comment: Yes, my web URL takes you to 1st page (INTRO) shows a clickable link, (my name) which takes you to the homepage, where a duplicate name image is seen for a few seconds and fades away, leaving the viewer to read the info on homepage and navigate my site from there. As the fade-image is associated with the homepage, each time homepage is visited from any other page in my site, the fade-iamge appears on load, NOT a good thing.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by grab that passed variable or what an 'if statement' is really. Man, I feel out of my depth!

Comment: check out this: http://jsbin.com/ekewis/edit#javascript,html.  you'll have to add the href="homepage.php?fade=true" to your logo on the intor page.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your time and help! The href in my intro pages html is "a href="home.html" so should i change it to a) href="homepage.html?fade=true" or b) substitute it with href="homepage.php?fade=true" ?

Comment: Hohum, cant figure out how to add code snippet in comments, so here is my intro pages href... [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/cress/PA2gR/ )

Comment: you would update your link on the logo to "a href="home.html?fade=true"  and then add the code from the jsbin that i posted to your javascript

Comment: I cant get it to work. I will try again tomorrow. I'm probably putting things in the wrong place.

Comment: changed the href in my intro page, added the javascript to my jquery file, put the main info from your html fiddle in my homepages html file, but no joy. After researching, i now understand what you meant by variables and if/else statements, but cant get it to work.